# How to develop a module for store rating. Magento 1.9 (store-view)

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, ratings

I need to get a module that the customer can use to review (rating) the store in general, and not the products. Is there any module that has this functionality? Or how could I develop it in magento 1

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid module "Shopreview" (current price is €55) support review store: https://www.magmodules.eu/magento1-shopreview.html